# Zend 2: OneToMany doesn't work in session

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm using standard Zend Authentication + Doctrine 2, when user log in and his credentials are valid I store data in session, but I noticed that when I retrieve user identity I can't get data from OneToMany relation.

**User.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    // email and password variables

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Profile
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Profile", mappedBy="assignedToUser")
     */
     protected $createdProfiles;
}
```

**Profile.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="profiles")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    // name, status + other irrelevant fields

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\User", inversedBy="createdProfiles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="assigned_to_user", referencedColumnName="id")
    **/
     private $assignedToUser;
}
```

Now, when I try to log in let's say on user's account ID 1

```
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

$auth = new AuthenticationService();
$authAdapter = new Adapter($username, $password);

$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

if ($result->isValid()) {
    foreach ($auth->getIdentity()->getcreatedProfiles() as $profile) {
        var_dump($profile->getName()) //                             works fine
    }
}
```

but when I do in other action:

```
public function myAction()
{
    $user = $this->identity()->getFirstName(); //                  works
    foreach ($this->identity()->getCreatedProfiles() as $profile) {
        var_dump($profile->getName()) //                           ! DOESN'T WORK !
    }

    $user = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\User')->find(1);

    $name = $user->getFirstName(); //                              works
    foreach ($user->getCreatedProfiles() as $profile) {
        var_dump($profile->getName()) //                           ! WORKS FINE !
    }
}
```

I tried add `cascade="refresh"` but looks like it doesn't work that way.

**Any idea why relation OneToMany doesn't work on object in session?**

Comment: Can you test to put fetch="EAGER" on your inverse side ?

Comment: @Hooli I have tried it before. I can get number of profiles created by user, but when I try: $profile->getStatus() I get following fatal error: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition **proxy_class_name** of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities saved into the session are not managed in the next request anymore. Read [the documentation on how to handle entities in the session](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html).

It is better to only save user id in the session and resolve the entity using the identifier:

```
$id = $this->identity();
$user = $entityManager->find(User::class, $id);
```

On top of that I see an issue in your entity definitions. You need to always [initialize your collections in the constructor](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#initialize-collections-in-the-constructor). So add to your `User` entity:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $createdProfiles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Forgetting this will also lead to issues when trying to do `getCreatedProfiles`.